# Deserialize JPA relationship using relation's id with Jackson

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jpa, jackson

I have two JPA annotated classes that have a relationship in the database. I'm using Jersey to expose a REST api.

```
//package and imports

@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Entity
public class Parent {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;
  private String name;

  //Getters and setters

}

//package and imports

@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Entity
public class Child {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;
  private String name;

  @ManyToOne
  private Parent parent;

  //Getters and setters
}
```

When I perform a `GET` request on `http://localhost/children` I get the following JSON:

```
[{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "child1",
  "parent": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "parent"
  }
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "child2",
  "parent": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "parent"
  }
}]
```

This is the model from the database serialized to JSON using Jackson.

When I perform a `POST` request to `http://localhost/children` to add a child using the following payload:

```
{
  "name": "child3",
  "parent": {
    "id": 1
  }
}
```

The child is persisted in the database but has a `null` value for parent name. I see this when I perform another `GET` on `http://localhost/children`

```
[{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "child1",
  "parent": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "parent"
  }
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "child2",
  "parent": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "parent"
  }
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "child3",
  "parent": {
    "id": 1
  }
}]
```

I used the `@JsonIdentityInfo/@JsonIdentityReference` method but this doesn't solve the problem. I don't want to put the entire Parent object as json in my `POST` request to add a child but only want to use the Parent id. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved it by using a the merge method of my EntityManager instead of persist. Then all data gets sent back to the client.